# Proof of $[0,1]~\text{disconnected}\implies(0,1)~\text{disconnected}$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I want to prove the following implication

$$[0,1]~\text{disconnected}\implies(0,1)~\text{disconnected}.$$

**My try:**
Suppose $[0,1]=U\cup V$ with $U,V$ open, disjoint and nonempty.

Using the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}$ we also have $U=U'\cap[0,1]$ and $V=V'\cap[0,1]$ where $U',V'$ are open in $\mathbb{R}$.

We have $(0,1)=(0,1)\cap[0,1]=(U'\cap(0,1))\cup(V'\cap(0,1))$. This is a union of open sets since $(0,1)$ is an open interval.

How can I prove that this is also a union of disjoint sets?

Will this $U\cap V=(U'\cap[0,1])\cap(V\cap[0,1])=U'\cap V'\cap[0,1]=\emptyset$ be sufficient for showing the disjoint-requirement?

Also, I do not know how to start for showing that $(0,1)$ is union of nonempty sets.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You could try to show $(0,1)~\text{connected}\implies[0,1]~\text{connected}$

Comment: $U$ and $V$ are disjoint. Since $U' \cap (0,1) \subset U$ and $V' \cap (0,1) \subset V$, it follows that $U' \cap (0,1)$ and $V' \cap (0,1)$ are disjoint. You need to show that they are both nonempty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, $[0,1]$ is connected so the implication follows trivially. Also, $[0,1]$ is disconnected implies that the Earth is flat, $2+2=5$ and anything else you'd like.

Comment: Well, I want to deduce from the implication that $[0,1]$ is connected. So, I cannot use it.

Comment: This question might be a step in a proof that $[0,1]$ is connected, which would make your proof circular...

Comment: @johnny09 If you want to prove that $[0,1]$ is connected, it's not that hard to do directly. See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339401/closed-unit-interval-is-connected-proof

Answer (score 1):

You just take off the points $0,1$.

$(0,1)=(U\setminus\{0,1\})\cup(V\setminus\{0,1\})$. Prove $U\setminus\{0,1\}$ and $V\setminus\{0,1\}$ are open in $(0,1)$ (follows almost trivially), non-empty (trivial) and disjoint (more trivial).